# How to restore original Deep Zoom images?

Tags: silverlight, jpeg, reverse, restore, deepzoom

Actually, I have a lot of collections of photos in Deep Zoom format. I would like to restore each image of each collection as a JPEG with the original size, is there a way to perform this ?

Answer (score 0):

In theory yes, in practice that may be difficult as there is no specific support to do that.

The problem is that all the images have been turned into squares in layers of different resolution and the position of the original images is lost. It is effective one enormous image once converted to DeepZoom.

To do what you want, you effectively want to iterate the entire Deep Zoom image, at its highest resolution, one row & column at a time - capturing a rendered image at each position.

There is however no obvious way to separate out the original images that made it (unless you have a fixed pattern to your picture layout e.g. laid out fixed sizes rows and columns).

Comment: A collection is just a collection of DZIs with information where they are on the canvas, so you *can* separate the images.

Comment: @Joey: Actually the final DZ images have little to do with the originals used to create it. They are transformed into multiple resolution layers, of fixed sizes with no overlap, and the originals are not kept.

Comment: Just take the highest resolution (which should usually be the input resolution) and put them together again. And they *can* have overlap.

Comment: @Joey: Which is what I suggested, but that does not help the asker... Please re-read the original question " I would like to restore each image of each collection as a JPEG with the *original size*, is there a way to perform this". I would suggest you post your own answer instead.